# When passing column name as parameter the query is showing incorrect output

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

This is my code.
  HEADER_ID is primary key.
  EFFECTIVE_DATE is column name and contains unique values.

```
declare @ColumnName varchar(20)
    set @ColumnName='EFFECTIVE_DATE'
     select * into #temphdrid 
     from  EMP_HEADER a 
    where 
    EMPLOYEE_ID in ('1111','2222') and  
    HEADER_ID=(select  max(HEADER_ID) from EMP_HEADER b where 
    a.HEADER_ID=b.HEADER_ID and    @ColumnName=(select MAX(@ColumnName) from EMP_HEADER c
    where b.EMPLOYEE_ID=c.EMPLOYEE_ID and YEAR(FIN_START_DATE)=2016)
    and YEAR(FIN_START_DATE)=2016)
    and YEAR(FIN_START_DATE)=2016
```

When I am   passing @ColumnName instead of EFFECTIVE_DATE  it is showing 10 rows, however it should show single row for each employee i.e. 2 in this case.

If I am directly passing EFFECTIVE_DATE  then it is working properly.

Please help as I am not able to understand what is the exact issue.

Comment: Looks like it would throw a syntax error because your brackets might be misplaced here `@ColumnName=(select MAX(@ColumnName) from EMP_HEADER c`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Long story short: what you are trying to do is not possible; you need to fix your approach.

When you declare variable `@ColumnName` it is not interpreted as a column name; it is always interpreted as a data value - in your case, it is the same as `'EFFECTIVE_DATE'` string literal. Effectively, your query works as if it were written as follows:

```
select * into #temphdrid 
from  EMP_HEADER a 
where 
EMPLOYEE_ID in ('1111','2222') and  
HEADER_ID=(select  max(HEADER_ID) from EMP_HEADER b where 
a.HEADER_ID=b.HEADER_ID
and 'EFFECTIVE_DATE'=(select MAX('EFFECTIVE_DATE') from EMP_HEADER c
where b.EMPLOYEE_ID=c.EMPLOYEE_ID and YEAR(FIN_START_DATE)=2016)
and YEAR(FIN_START_DATE)=2016)
and YEAR(FIN_START_DATE)=2016
```

This is syntactically correct, but it makes no sense, because `MAX('EFFECTIVE_DATE')` is always equal to `'EFFECTIVE_DATE'`.

An alternative approach would be providing some indication for what column name needs to be selected, and using a `case` expression for the comparison:

```
declare @ColIdx tinyint
set @ColIdx=1
...
where 
a.HEADER_ID=b.HEADER_ID
and (case @ColInd when 1 then EFFECTIVE_DATE when 2 then END_DATE else null end)=(select MAX(case @ColInd when 1 then EFFECTIVE_DATE when 2 then END_DATE else null end) from
```

Comment: @Shardul You are welcome! If you are no longer looking for help with this question, please consider accepting the answer by clicking the check mark next to it. This would let other visitors of the site know that your problem has been solved, and earn you a new badge on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

Dynamic query is the only way if you are going to pass different columns names in that variable

```
declare @ColumnName varchar(20)
    set @ColumnName='EFFECTIVE_DATE'

Declare @sql varchar(max) = ''
set @ColumnName=QUOTENAME(@ColumnName)

  set @sql =  '  select * into #temphdrid 
     from  EMP_HEADER a 
    where 
    EMPLOYEE_ID in ('1111','2222') and  
    HEADER_ID=(select  max(HEADER_ID) from EMP_HEADER b where 
    a.HEADER_ID=b.HEADER_ID and    '+ @ColumnName +' =(select MAX('+ @ColumnName +') from EMP_HEADER c
    where b.EMPLOYEE_ID=c.EMPLOYEE_ID and YEAR(FIN_START_DATE)=2016)
    and YEAR(FIN_START_DATE)=2016)
    and YEAR(FIN_START_DATE)=2016'

Exec (@sql)
```

**Note :** The temp table created inside the dynamic query cannot be accessed outside. If you want to access outside then create table in prior and use `INSERT INTO #temphdrid  SELECT..` inside dynamic query

Comment: Best make the type of ColumnName a `SYSNAME` (The sysname data type is used for table columns, variables, and stored procedure parameters that store object names.)

Comment: Alternatively, `INSERT ... INTO ##temphdrid` would be possible as well.

Comment: :) Sorry I did after I wrote that comment, sorries!

Comment: @Prdp Thanks for the solution. It will work but I want to use the temporary table for fetching values without creating physical table.